# How to link against msvcr90.dll with mingw gcc?

Tags: gcc, mingw, msvcr90.dll

How to link against msvcr90.dll with mingw gcc? I tried -lmsvcr90, here's the minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s\n", "hello");
    return 0;
}
```

My OS is win7, with mingw gcc 4.5.0

```
$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 4.5.0 (GCC)
$ gcc hello.c -lmsvcr90
$ a
```

Then I got this error:

**R6034**

```
    An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
    Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Which part am I missing ?

edit1:

@user440813 Seems my mingw is very different from yours.

```
$ gcc h.c -nostdlib -lmsvcr70 -lgcc -o h.exe
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/libgcc.a(__main.o):(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `atexit'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/libgcc.a(__main.o):(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `atexit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I mocked `int atexit ( void ( * function ) (void) ) {return 0;}` and got **R6034** again ...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
gcc hello.c -nostdlib -lmsvcr90 -lgcc -o hello.exe
```

instead. I'm a little surprised that your original compilation attempt succeeded, since there should've been conflicting definitions between `msvcr90` and `msvcrt` (which MinGW links in by default). This way, `msvr90` gets linked in, the conflicting `msvcrt` doesn't, but `libgcc` gets added in order to initialize the runtime library.

I don't have `msvcr90.dll` on my computer, but I was able to verify that the analogous invocation works with `msvcr100.dll`.