# Can I zip all the python standard libs and the python still able to import it?

Tags: python

I read a tutorial that you can compile all the libs files to .pyc, then pack all the .pyc as a zipped file. Then the python still works as magic and it becomes significantly smaller.
But when I zipped all the .pyc files as python36.zip and saved them under /lib/python3.6. Tried to start python, the python says it cannot find module codecs.

What did I do wrong? Can someone explain will this actually work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Python egg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051192/what-is-a-python-egg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import modules from a `.zip` file, [you need to add that file to `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) - then it will act as a search directory. The `zipimport` module that does the job is a built-in one.

---

`sys.path` is constructed like this:

- [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable + value calculated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=pythonpath#sys.path) from a compiled-in default (`PYTHONPATH` macro in `pyconfig.h`)

  - [The calculated value includes a path to a `.zip` file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PC/getpathp.c#L697) that may or may not exist.
- Then `site` is imported [that does the following](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html):

  - [looks for and adds user-specific `site-packages`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/site.py#L561)
  - [looks for system-wide `site-packages` directories under `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/site.py#L331).

    - when calculating both `sys` properties, the interpreter [does a number of tests](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/getpath.c#L13) that includes looking for `os.py` file and `lib-dynload` directory where they should normally be
  - scans the `site-packages` directories for `.pth` files and appends their lines to `sys.path`, treating them as paths relative to the file's location.

---

So, you can move all the standard modules into the predefined `.zip` file. But you may need to leave an `os.py` or `lib-dynload` if `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` become blank after that (the contents are irrelevant, the moved modules will be imported from the `.zip` because it's earlier on `sys.path`), or you will lose access to all 3rd-party modules.

Subdirectories that have their own entry in `sys.path` you need to handle separately so that their contents can still be found on `sys.path`.

<sub>(tested in Python 2.7-`win32`)</sub>

---

Though adding `.pyc` files to the archive is sufficient, `pdb` and stacktraces will be useless unless you place `.py`s there as well.

Comment: I checked the sys.path variable and zipped everything as python36 and it works like charm. The only directory I have to leave is the lib-dyload. Cause python calls the dynamic lib from this folder. It seems it is the only thing I cannot zip.

Comment: @J.R. you cannot zip `libpythonX.Y.so` because it's the Python engine. [`.so` files that are Python extension modules, you should be able to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601950/load-pyd-files-from-a-zip-from-embedded-python). Just watch that they still can be found on `sys.path` under the same module names. The directory entry itself is tested for in `sys.exec_prefix` search though (updated the answer) so you may need to leave it be.