# In what header is qsort_s located in MingGW (gcc 4.8) for Windows?

Tags: gcc, header-files, gcc-warning, mingw-w64

I am getting "implicit declaration of function 'qsort_s'" warning which means GCC doesn't find it in headers included. I am including:

```
windows.h
stdlib.h
string.h
search.h (given as requirement in visual studio documentation)
```

I am somehow unable to google for location of either qsort_s or qsort_r (I've read that they provide the same functionality - allowing to pass context to comparator function).

Anyone knows how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my copy of `mingw-w64` (recent trunk) it isn't defined at all. The `mingw` folks must have missed it. It is defined in `msvcr90.def` and later so, so it is in the import libraries...

I suggest you file an upstream bug, define it yourself in the meantime (get the definition from MSDN) and [link accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3402252/484441).

Comment: it's somehow including what is needed at link time because the code works despite the warning during compilation;

Comment: As I said... It is in the import libraries, but not in the headers. Also if you compile on Windows, chances are that the linker will actually create a temp. on-the-fly import library from DLLs you're about to link if it can find it, IIRC. Since the `msvcrt.dll` that comes with recent Windows versions does include `qsort_s`, it may be entirely possible it got it from there. You may `-v` link your stuff to get more information and/or use something like (Dependency Walker)[http://www.dependencywalker.com/] to find out what actual DLL the symbol is imported from.